# asyncio Streamwriter sending multiple writes

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I was hoping someone could help me come up with a solution for the following issue. I want to send two write requests to asyncio, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

### Server

```py
async def upload_data(reader, writer):
    request = await reader.read(-1)
    data = await reader.read(-1)
```

### Client

```py
import json

reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8000)

# Metadata about the data about to be sent
request = {
    "data_type": "test",
    "data_name": "test_data_1"
}
writer.write(json.dumps(req).encode("UTF-8")
writer.write_eof()
await writer.drain()

# Actual data to be sent
with open("test.dat", "rb") as f:
    writer.write(f.read())
    writer.write_eof()
    await writer.drain()
```

### Error

```py
RuntimeError: Cannot call write() after write_eof()
```

#### Things I've tried:

1. Sending data from the server to the client in between the writes. I hoped this would reset the writer. It didn't.
2. Not sending the first *write_eof*. This causes both the request and data to be combined and I can't figure out how to split the bytes reliably.
3. Trying *reader.read(1000)* and not sending *write_eof*. Unfortunately both *req* and *data* can fluctuate in size and this method can cause both writes to bleed into each other.
4. Appending data into the request. *eg: request["data"] = f.read()*. *json.dumps* did not like this at all.
5. Opening two separate connections. This would cause *upload_data* to be ran from the start again, saving *data* under *request*, and then it would block forever waiting for more data.

Once again, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW stufing the data into the request would have worked, but you should encode the (possibly binary) data in a Unicode-friendly way, e.g. using base64. For example, `request["data"] = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('ascii')` and on the other side, `data = base64.base64decode(request["data"])`. You can use ASCII as the encoding because base64 only uses ascii chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As asyncio warns you, sending an EOF makes the stream unusable for further writing. If you need to combine multiple messages inside a single TCP stream, you will need to invent a *protocol* for embedding the messages into the stream - or reuse one of a multitude of protocols already invented for such purposes (such as [http](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web.html)).

For small scripts, a very simple protocol is to just prefix each message with a line specifying the message length:

```
async def send_message(octets, writer):
    writer.write(b'%d\n' % len(octets))
    writer.write(octets)
    await writer.drain()

async def recv_message(reader):
    prefix = await reader.readline()
    msglen = int(prefix)
    return await reader.readexactly(msglen)
```

With that in place, your server would look like this:

```
async def upload_data(reader, writer):
    request = await recv_message(reader)
    data = await recv_message(reader)
    ...
```

and the client like this:

```
await send_message(json.dumps(req).encode("UTF-8"))
with open("test.dat", "rb") as f:
    await send_message(f.read())
```