# Ensure StreamReader handles one message at a time

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using the [aioisotp library](https://github.com/christiansandberg/aioisotp) and sometimes messages are received close together. This means that aioisotp can, on occasion, provide 2 messages combined together.
For example,

```
03 7F 36 78 00 00 00 00
02 76 02 00 00 00 00 00
```

I receive these 2 messages <2ms apart. `aioisotp` returns it as one combined message: `7f36787602`

What I believe is happening:

- `StreamReader.feed_data()` is receiving the first message (7F3678) and adds to the buffer.
- It then flags for the `read()` to consume the data using `_wakeup_waiter()` which sets the result on the `future()`
- Before the `read()` can be scheduled to consume the data, the second message (7602) is received; and `StreamReader.feed_data()` is called and the buffer is **extended** with the new data. So, the buffer now contains 7F36787602.
- The `read()` now occurs and both pieces of data are received together.

There is nothing in the received data to tell me this is >1 message so I need to ensure the order of one `feed_data()` followed by `read()`.

As a test, in `StreamReader.feed_data()` I changed `self._buffer.extend(data)` to `self._buffer=bytearray(data)`

Whilst this worked, it doesn't feel like the correct way of handling this. What would be the correct way to ensure `read()` only gets one message at a time?

Comment: Don't know about ISO-TP, but `StreamReader` expects *streaming data*, such as that coming from a TCP/IP socket or from a pipe. Such data has no concept of "messages", only a stream of bytes. Even if the peer sends individual bursts, those may be merged or separated at any point. If you need to send individual messages over such a stream, you need to add explicit _framing_ (such as a length prefix, or a separator that cannot appear in the message).

Comment: I figured the same so I changed it so the library adds a length prefix. As I suspected, I was getting some data loss with the hack mentioned in the question.

Comment: I've now added a response with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StreamReader` expects *streaming* data, such as that coming from a TCP/IP socket or from a pipe. Such data has no concept of "messages", only a stream of bytes. Even if the peer sends bytes in individual bursts, those may be merged or split up by the sender's or the receiver's OS, or by the network equipment between them. No change to `feed_data` or other part of asyncio can fix that in the general case.

If you need to send individual messages over a TCP stream, you need to add explicit *framing*. For example, you can prefix the message with the message length, or you can insert a separator that cannot appear in the message between two messages. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384980/1600898) for an example of the former.